# Unable to use annotate feature in Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: 20.04

I am unable to use the annotation feature in Ubuntu 20.04.
I already installed these things using this command

```
sudo apt-get install compizconfig-settings-manager compiz-plugins compiz-plugins-extra
```

[image: CompizConfig Settings Manager]

I tried to enable the annotation feature using <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>left mouse button</kbd>, but this shortcut didn't enable this feature.

How to use this feature in Ubuntu 20.04?

Comment: Why are you attempting to install Compiz? Are you running the Unity desktop? The standard Ubuntu desktop uses Mutter, not Compiz, as window manager.

Comment: I am using Ubuntu Desktop. I don't know much about it. I found it in some online blog that's why I installed it. Please help me how to install it properly?

Comment: It is always better to directly ask about the problem you want to solve, not about the, possibly wrong, solutions you are attempting. In the mean time, there are some answers that indicate how you can implement drawing on the screen in standard Ubuntu. That is a very good extension indeed.

Answer (score 3):

You can use the [Draw On Your Screen](https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/1683/draw-on-you-screen/) GNOME Shell extension.

Refer to this question on how to install GNOME Shell extensions: [How do I install and manage GNOME Shell extensions?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/75530/how-do-i-install-and-manage-gnome-shell-extensions)

After installing, you can toggle the extension on and off by pressing <kbd>Super</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>D</kbd>.

The extension offers a plethora of annotation settings, accessible by right-clicking with the extension enabled:

[image]

Here are some [Tips and Tricks](https://salsa.debian.org/gnome-team/shell-extensions/gnome-shell-extension-draw-on-your-screen#tips-and-tricks) on using the extension.

---

Also remove the Compiz packages that you installed, as they have no use on GNOME, by running:

```
sudo apt-get purge compizconfig-settings-manager compiz-plugins compiz-plugins-extra
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Could you please tell me what is super?

Comment: @RishiPurwar It is most likely the key with the Windows logo.

Comment: No arrow shape makes it useless really!

Answer (score 2):

This is possible with latest Ubuntu MATE 20.04 LTS.

All you need is to switch to MATE DE by

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install ubuntu-mate-desktop^
```

Then select its session on login screen, install the Compiz-related stuff here by:

```
sudo apt-get install compiz compiz-core compiz-mate compiz-plugins compiz-plugins-default compiz-plugins-extra compizconfig-settings-manager
```

Then run MATE Tweak to select Compiz decorator on **Windows** tab, **Window manager** → **Compiz**.

And finally enable Annotate in the CCSM as you have planned to do. Personally I have added `<Shift><Alt><Super>Button3` shortcut for **Clear**.

Then enjoy:

[image: annotate with Compiz on Ubuntu MATE 20.04 LTS]

Comment: Thanks for your answer

Answer (score 1):

Since 17.10, Ubuntu hasn't used Compiz (as part of the Unity desktop) as part of the default desktop. As such I don't think you're going to successfully use that method for annotating your screen.

We now use GNOME Shell, which uses a concept of extensions to add features to the desktop experience. One such extension is called [Draw On You(r) Screen](https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/1683/draw-on-you-screen/). Perhaps that could work for you?