# How to draw using pencil/ marker in Ubuntu desktop screen while screen recording the screen?

Tags: compiz, desktop-recording, video-recording, capture, vector-drawings

I use Vokoscreen-ng for screen recording. it doesn't have pencil/ marker / brush to highlight the recording screen in Ubuntu. Some says Compiz will help. I can't find pencil/ marker option.

Comment: What is the question? What version of Ubuntu?

Comment: For MATE with Compiz see https://askubuntu.com/a/1295733/66509 .

Answer (score 0):

There is an excellent Gnome Shell extension to draw on the screen. Install it with the command

```
sudo apt install gnome-shell-extension-draw-on-your-screen
```

At least, this will work on Ubuntu 21.04. The extension may not be available in Ubuntu software on Ubuntu 20.04. If the above command indicates the package is not found, then you can install the extension from the Gnome Shell Extensions website.